# Having problems adding 3d points to existing 3d scatterplot

Tags: r, 3d, scatter-plot

I'm currently attempting to generate a 3d scatterplot for my project. As you can see below I've subset the species column into three different subsets to seperate out the three species. I'm managing to generate the scatterplot fine with one of the three data sets but I'm having problems adding points to the existing scatterplot from the other two data sets. Is there something I'm doing wrong or something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Brooke

Data:

```
Species      Mid_X    Mid_Y     Mid_Z 
Cod         -226.483    290.807 -1770.277
Cod          624.474    280.285 -1762.328
Cod          665.449    243.107 -1961.12
Cod         -561.352    297.365 -1843.93
Cod         -513.858    361.52  -1957.867
Haddock       61.303    -172.153    -1482.718
Haddock       57.876    -244.111    -1278.529
Haddock      209.822    -195.276    -1287.596
Haddock      486.066    -186.823    -1628.798
Whiting      260.514    -232.993    -1301.227
Whiting     71.793  35.854  -1173.601
Whiting     4.147   -44.185 -1282.338
```

Code:
    WCC <- read.csv("WaterColumnCurrent.csv")
    Cod <- subset(WCC, Species == "Cod")
    Haddock <- subset(WCC, Species == "Haddock")
    Whiting <- subset(WCC, Species == "Whiting")

```
scatterplot3d(Cod$Mid_X, Cod$Mid_Z, Cod$Mid_Y, pch=20)
points3d(Haddock$Mid_X, Haddock$Mid_Z, Haddock$Mid_Y, pch=2)
```

Comment: Are you using the scatterplot3d library or rgl?  In order to add points using the scatterplot3d library, you need to use the output from the scatterplot3d function.  The way you have it set up now, you are calling scatterplot3d and then points3d from rgl.

Comment: I literally just managed to solve my own problem. Named the scatterplot CWC and then when adding points used code: CWC$points3d(Haddock$Mid_X, Haddock$Mid_Z, Haddock$Mid_Y, pch=2). This managed to fix the problem. Thanks for your help though, darwin.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little breakdown of the difference (after my vague comment), with some code.

Using scatterplot3d library:

```
spl <- scatterplot3d(WCC$Mid_X, WCC$Mid_Z, WCC$Mid_Y, pch=20, type="n")
spl$points3d(Haddock$Mid_X, Haddock$Mid_Z, Haddock$Mid_Y, pch=2)
```

Or using the rgl library:

```
plot3d(WCC$Mid_X, WCC$Mid_Z, WCC$Mid_Y, pch=20, type="n")
points3d(Haddock$Mid_X, Haddock$Mid_Z, Haddock$Mid_Y, pch=2)
```