# Marking a specific point on 3d scatterplot R

Tags: r, 3d, scatter-plot

I'm using R package graphics to plot 3d scatterplots in R. I would like to mark a specific point on this plot in a different color, in the same way we use plot() and lines() on 2d plots.

How can I do that on the 3d scatterplot?

```
#Set plot points
x = seq(-10, 10, length= 100)
y = x
fr = function(x, y) { r = sqrt(x^2+y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
z = outer(x, y, fr)
z[is.na(z)] = 1
#Plot using scatterplot 3d
X = expand.grid(x,y)
x = X[,1]
y = X[,2]
z = c(z)
scatterplot3d(x,y,z,color="lightblue",pch=21,main="3-D Scatter Plot")
#Get maximum for this function
fn = function(x) { r = sqrt(x[1]^2+x[2]^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
optim(c(-1.2,1,4), fn, method = "Nelder-Mead")
#Mark maximum on the graph in different color
#How to??
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531285/having-problems-adding-3d-points-to-existing-3d-scatterplot

Comment: you might want to check out `?optim`. By default, `optim` performs minimization but will maximize if `control$fnscale` is negative.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I made the correction on optim and now it is maximizing.